# How to catch every exception thrown in a webmethod but without those exceptions interrupting the execution of the program

Tags: asp.net, jquery, exception

Is there any way I can make that every exception thrown inside a webmethod go straight to the jQuery Ajax error callback function?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "MantenimientoNotasCapacidades.aspx/SaveViaWebService",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {               


        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText).d;
            var error = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(JSON.parse(request.responseText).error.message);

        }
    });
```

I know that using **JSON.parse(request.responseText).Message** should be enough to show the information for that error but all I've got now  is that every time an exception is raised the code stops right there , being necessary to keep pressing F10 or F5 to finally be able to see the alert.

I already tried enclosing my code in a 'try' block but I don't see much point in doing that since I can't do much in the 'catch' block as I'd do in a visual basic application where I could use the 'catch' block to show the exception message in a  MsgBox.

Is there any way to catch in the error callback function all the exceptions thrown in a webmethod but without them stopping the execution of the code?

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. Happy new year!!

Comment: Why is the `try` block not working? Is it not possible to build return json inside the `catch` block, return a 500, and handle it in the `error` function? If you have already tried this and it didn't work, then you might have forgot to change the response code -- in which case it would be a 200, and your error json was actually being sent to your success callback.

Comment: @cmd.prompt thanks to your comment I was finally able to send the error to the error callback. Now I've only got one question left. Please take a look to the answer I added to my question

Answer (score 1):

Following @cmd.promt's advice, I changed the Response.StatusCode to 500 and created and object(**myError**) containing the description for the exception that was thrown, then the only thing left to do was to serialize the object and send it back to the client (Here I tried to use Response..Write("{""message"": ""action failed!""}") but for some reason I always ended up getting the same error : ***"JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data"*** so in the end I decided to go with [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and forget all about **response.Write**)

```
<WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Function SaveViaWebService(lst As List(Of Students)) As String
          Try

          Catch ex As Exception


                Dim httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
                httpResponse.Clear()
                httpResponse.StatusCode = 500

                'I thought that .StatusDescription would be useful but it turned out it didn't
                'httpResponse.StatusDescription = ex.Message

                Dim myError= New With {.message = ex.Message, .source = ex.Source}
                Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myError)

            End Try
        End Function
```

And with that, the error is correctly sent to the error callback , where the only thing I had to do was to play with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see how the error has been sent 
[image]

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "MantenimientoNotasCapacidades.aspx/SaveViaWebService",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {               


        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText).d;
            var error = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(JSON.parse(request.responseText).error.message);

        }
    });
```

Thus far, everything is as I as wanted it , except for the exceptions that keep on interrupting the execution of the program. **Is that their normal behaviour ?? Aren't they all supposed to go directly to the 'catch' block??**